# Weird Permissions Issue in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, permissions

My SharePoint site uses Active Directory authentication. The Site Visitors SharePoint group contains the AD group of all users.

I have a subsite which Site Visitors have Read access to. Inside this subsite, I have a document library which I **don't** want visitors to have read access to and so I have made the permissions unique for this document library only and only allowed 2 explicit users to have access to it.

Despite this, I can still come onto the site as a Site Visitor AD user and navigate to this document library and read the files inside.

Any idea what's going on here? I should be able to lock down lists and doc libs like this shouldn't I?

Hope someone has seen an issue like this before. Are there any pages I can view which show me what users/groups have permission to this document library other than the standard Permissions one?

Thanks

Graeme

Comment: Can you check the permissions on the files themselves? i.e. hover over item -> manage permissions?

Comment: Thing is they shouldn't even be able to see the list at all? I went and checked and the files all inherit the permissions of the parent, i.e. the list.

Comment: And you are sure you are not a member of an AD group that does have permission? are you logged in as the site admin?

Comment: The 2 users who should have access to the list are both admin users and the user I'm logged in as is just a member of the Site Visitors group.

Comment: hmm gonna try it here, will let you know

Comment: Thanks much appreciated - from everything I've read, it's doing it wrong. Permissions work downwards and at any time can be cut off from inheriting from their parent allowing lists to have their own permissions. Can't see why this is happening at all...

Comment: Yeah that should work correctly the way you have it set up. If you set the permissions of your list to break inheritance, then only those two user's should see it. My only other thought is that your account you are testing with is a Site Administrator or something like that.

Comment: tried it on my dev machine and get an access denied error. Are you sure the permissionset of the visitor group in sharepoint have not ben changed through site settings -> advanced permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to try out the [Permissions Reporting Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/08/27/announcing-the-fourth-release-of-the-microsoft-sharepoint-administration-toolkit.aspx) just today new version has been released.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I'll try using this on the site to see what the issues are. I'll accept this answer since it's drawn my attention to it

Answer (score 0):

Hey there, I'm Kevin and I work on SharePoint permissions

If the users are site collection administrators, they will have access to the list regardless of the permissions set.